# Why $_POST is empty in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, web-services, php-curl

I have created a simple Rest webservice with Codeigniter.
When i send post data with Curl from another application and display $_POST is empty.

Simple PHP client:

```php
$url = 'http://localhost/ci-access/api_v1/register_events';
$data = array(
    'name' => 'tester'
);
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$output  = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Codeigniter webservice:

```php
public function register_events() {
    die(var_dump($_POST));
}
```

Is there an option to set in Codeigniter ?
How can i read posted data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try pass `php curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);` option first or remove it.